# How to log custom entries in 'Recent log entries'?

Tags: log-messages

I am developing a custom module, and I'd like to log my own log entries with their own ***type***, so that they can be accessed and filtered at `admin/reports/dblog`.

But I can't find the appropiate function or script. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`watchdog()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/6) is what you are looking for. See the description of its parameters, in particular these:

> `$type`: The category to which this message belongs. Can be any string, but the general practice is to use the name of the module calling `watchdog()`. The `$type` parameter is limited to 16 characters; anything longer is truncated.
>
> `$severity`: The severity of the message; one of the following values as defined in [RFC 3164](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3164.html):
>
> - `WATCHDOG_EMERGENCY`: Emergency, system is unusable.
> - `WATCHDOG_ALERT`: Alert, action must be taken immediately.
> - `WATCHDOG_CRITICAL`: Critical conditions.
> - `WATCHDOG_ERROR`: Error conditions.
> - `WATCHDOG_WARNING`: Warning conditions.
> - `WATCHDOG_NOTICE`: (default) Normal but significant conditions.
> - `WATCHDOG_INFO`: Informational messages.
> - `WATCHDOG_DEBUG`: Debug-level messages.
>
> `$link`: A link to associate with the message.

Answer (score 0):

A possibly alternative for logging custom log entries, is to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module:

- The Drupal 6 version of Rules has the ability to create a watchdog entry.
- This functionality is not (yet) present in an official D7 release, but there is a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1349882#comment-6190164) available to do so in D7 also.

For D7, you can also use the [Better Watchdog UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_watchdog_ui) module, which comes with [Rules Watchdog Integration](https://www.drupal.org/node/2040213). Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> Upgrade watchdog entries to entities and replace default database log listing with a view, which grants advanced filtering options and filtered deletion as a bulk operation.
>
> The module creates an entity wrapper around database log entries and enhances the watchdog listing by replacing it with a view. Beside type and severity, additional filter options were introduced such as date and author.
>
> The possibility to change the number of listed entries per page has also been added.
>
> Database clearing has also been customized, now admins can clear only the filtered entries, if needed.
>
> The provided view is accessible to the admins and can be fully customized as any view, to fit one's needs.